# How to make slf4j log to different outputs

Tags: java, slf4j

I am performing logging using Slf4J (slf4j-simple), and I would like to be able to output logs to both standard output and to a log file. I also want to be able to log different events to different log files.

For example: I would like to be able to log one "class" of events to a "mainevents.log" file, while another class of events can go to "messages.log".

I know that the closest thing that slf4j has to the ability to classify events is the Marker. Unfortunately, it is unclear if there is any way to send logs to different files based on markers. It is also unclear how to configure slf4j so that it can output logs to more than one output at the same time. There appears to be a dearth of documentation on how to configure slf4j logging.

Does anyone know how to make slf4j log to more than one output at the same time? Also: can someone tell how to log to different log files based on different markers?

Comment: You need to choose a Log implementation of SLF4J, such as Log4J or Logback. Then according to the Log implementation you use, please configure the corresponding configuration file (log4j.xml or logback.xml).

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @life888888. It depends on the log implementation framework. In Log4j2, you can specify the location to which the logs should go to by mentioning the appender in the logger specification.

```
<logger name="SYSTEM_OUT" level="info" additivity="false">
   <appender-ref ref="Default" />
   <appender-ref ref="Console" />
</logger>
```